# Auto increment in C#

Tags: c#, auto-increment, mysql-workbench

How can I enable auto increment primary key in c# when connected to database in mysql? I'm looking for a way when I add a data to the database using C# it will automatically give me an ID that will be in order. For example I am a manager in a company and I want to add a new item that I do't need to enter the id.

Comment: You put an auto increment column in the table which will increment for each insert,you dont need to add it each time.

Comment: This has nothing to do with C#. It is a property of your column. See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)

Comment: You realize that C# is just talking to the database? It's MySQL's job to assign ID numbers, not C#'s.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth. But my column is already auto increment. Even when I get the value of ID to my program it doesn't increment.

Comment: Show us how you “get the value of ID”.

Comment: @user3314170: You need to provide a lot more info, e.g. how you access the database etc. Show some code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is normally the database's job. Set column for the ID to be auto incrementing. Write the query in such a way that it rereads the just inserted row (as a stored procedure or as an insert/select pair). Now you have your unique ID right after insert. HTH

Answer (score 0):

You can set Id column in database as Auto Increment you don't need to do it from C#. if you want to do it then select the last inserted Id and then add your static increment mask to it and then insert this new Id to database.